# Unable to connect via NetBIOS Name

Tags: networking, windows-7, network-share, file-sharing, netbios

I can't connect to machines/shares by NetBIOS names. Below is console output showing the problem.

```
C:\>nbtstat -n

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.100] Scope Id: []

                NetBIOS Local Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    BEAST          <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered
    BEAST          <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <1E>  GROUP       Registered
    WORKGROUP      <1D>  UNIQUE      Registered
    ..__MSBROWSE__.<01>  GROUP       Registered


C:\>nbtstat -A 192.168.1.3

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.100] Scope Id: []

           NetBIOS Remote Machine Name Table

       Name               Type         Status
    ---------------------------------------------
    BRCLAPTOP      <00>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <00>  GROUP       Registered
    BRCLAPTOP      <20>  UNIQUE      Registered
    WORKGROUP      <1E>  GROUP       Registered

    MAC Address = 00-1C-BF-14-B8-6E

C:\>ping beast

Pinging beast [fe80::59b8:179f:b90b:a63f%11] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::59b8:179f:b90b:a63f%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::59b8:179f:b90b:a63f%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::59b8:179f:b90b:a63f%11: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::59b8:179f:b90b:a63f%11: time<1ms

Ping statistics for fe80::59b8:179f:b90b:a63f%11:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\>ping brclaptop
Ping request could not find host brclaptop. Please check the name and try again.

C:\>nbtstat -a brclaptop

Local Area Connection:
Node IpAddress: [192.168.1.100] Scope Id: []

    Host not found.
```

Comment: Is Network Discovery enabled on both computers? LLMNR requires Network Discovery to be enabled. Barring that, is NetBios over TCP enabled on both computers? For single label name resolution, name resolution should attempt to resolve the name via LLMNR, then NetBIOS over TCP (in addition to looking in th local name cache and in the LMHOSTS file).

Comment: Are you running only IPv6? NetBIOS does not work over IPv6, add IPv4 protocols if you wish to continue using NetBIOS. If you have both IPv6 and IPv4, you could remove IPv6 if you don't need it.

Comment: Out of curiousity, what is the netmask on each machine? /24 (i.e. 255.255.255.0)? Or something different? NetBIOS name query requests use broadcasts, so if your netmask is wrong, broadcasts could be directed to an incorrect address, which means NetBIOS name resolution will fail.

Answer (score -1):

This problem may be occured by your workgroup. have you installed a DNS on your brclaptop to make a domain group for your local network. 
On my site this is working fine by using domain group.
I am not sure but I hope this help you some.

Answer (score -1):

If I recall correctly, you cant connect to bios names from a different domain/workgroup, only the ip address.